# android: How to check flash if on/off/auto?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera, android-camera

So I'm trying to have a button where users can choose between flash on/off/auto. This button is within my camera preview activity, but I'm not sure how to check certain parameters with one button.

```
    //Flash Button
    final Button flashButton = (Button) findViewById(id.camera_flash);
    flashButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mCamera != null){
                Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("AUTO");
                Log.e("Torch","Torch On");
            }else{
                Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera=null;
                flashButton.setText("OFF");

            }// maybe another one for ON



        }
```

Right now its setting if `mCamera!=null` but then how do I check if flash is AUTO, ON, or OFF? I'm thinking that there maybe a SWITCH instead? I'm trying to keep these settings in one button, so its kind of a toggle. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATED CODE

```
   //Flash Button
    final Button flashButton = (Button) findViewById(id.camera_flash);
    flashButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(p.getFlashMode() == android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("Off");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE OFF");

            }else if(p.getFlashMode() == android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera=null;
                flashButton.setText("TORCH");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE TORCH");

            }else if(p.getFlashMode() == android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("ON");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE ON");

            }else if(p.getFlashMode() == android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("AUTO");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE AUTO");

            }else{
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("AUTO");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE AUTO");

            }



        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can  check if flash is AUTO, ON, or OFF as:

```
Camera.Parameters p= mCamera.getParameters();

if(p.getFlashMode().equals(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))
{
 //DO STUFF...
}
else if(p.getFlashMode().equals(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
{
//DO STUFF......
}
else if(p.getFlashMode().equals(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
{
//DO STUFF......
}
else if(p.getFlashMode().equals(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO))
{
//DO STUFF......
}
else
{
//DO STUFF.....
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I implemented this code, but I think it only goes to the else section. I tried to press the button again, but nothing happens. Why is this? I'm trying to toggle the button, but I think it stops after one press?

Comment: I updated my post, does it make sense? Thanks for take the time to help me! Really appreciate it

Comment: I'm trying to read the tutorial, but my question is, is the button I have set supposed to be correct for multiple clicks? or is there another button for this type of button?

Comment: yes your button is correct for multiple click but i'm not conform why it's behaving as

Comment: because the other answer is the true correct one, its not `==`, but its `.equals()`, If someone else comes here looking for the same question, they would like to have an answer that will work for them. I answered it correctly because it gave me towards the right direction, but the other guy answered it with the correct syntax

Comment: @andrewliu : but i answered you on 12th May when u are facing problem and this guy answered your problem after 15th days when your problem get solved  so if you have any issue with == (but it's also working with ==)you just edit this answer.this is not right way for responding guy who answer your questions.thanks friend

Comment: How it is the `mCamera` defined ?

Comment: @Spritzig instance return by `Camera.open()`

Comment: Can you be more specific how you define the `Camera` I have tried `Camera mCamera = new Camera()` it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

You need to compare the values with the equals() method instead of "==", because the values are strings.

```
Camera.Parameters p= mCamera.getParameters();
String flashMode = p.getFlashMode();
if(flashMode == null) {
 //DO something, if it has no value
} else if(flashMode.equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
  //DO STUFF......
} else if(flashMode.equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
//DO STUFF......
}
  :
  :
```